# Trying to express a mind state - sentence correctnesss

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I'm writing a letter to my employer regarding getting education assistance for my Master's program. My question: are there errors? what can I do to express this sentiment better? Should I split this in different sentences as in (option 2)

Option 1: The master’s program will keep me in a mind state of “active learning” which will enable me to learn the different <Company X's> systems faster.

Option 2: The master's program will keep me in a mind state of "active learning". This will enable me to learn the different <Company X's> systems faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you whether you want to combine or split the sentences.  I tend to prefer shorter sentences, as they are easier to parse.  You are less likely to make mistakes in a short sentence.